# Angular ng-grid filter on only two columns

Tags: angularjs

I want to do an either or kind of query on ng-grid where it searches both columns with the same filter text.

I've figured out how to filter on a per column basis, but what I would like to do is filter on two columns with the same input.

var searchQuery = 'college:' + collegeText + ";" + 'curriculumName:' + $scope.filterText + 'department:' + $scope.filterText + ';';

Doesn't seem to work. I have to remove either department or curriculumName to get a result. Apparently, it thinks it needs to find it in both columns to return a result.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on this [resource](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/workbench/index5.html). Checkout the repo and load the page in the browser.

Basically, you can rely on the `filterChanged` event. Assuming you have a search bar as follows in the HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filteringText" placeholder="Search..." class="search-query"/>
```

The JavaScript part will look like:

```
// Initialize
$scope.filteringText = '';

$scope.filterOptions = {
    filterText: 'filteringText',
    useExternalFilter: false
};

// Configure ng-grid.
$scope.gridOptions = {
    ...
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
    ...
};

$scope.$on('filterChanged', function (evt, text) {
    console.log(text);
    $scope.filteringText = text;
});
```

Comment: This will apply the filter over all columns in the grid and not just the two columns that he wants to filter on.